# Token returned by JWTAuth is not as expected, console.log gives not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, jwt, satellizer, json-web-token

The token returned my JWTAuth and Laravel is not defined. The localstorage shows

```
satellizer_token: [object Object]
```

AuthController

```
protected function createToken($user)
{
    $customClaims = [
        'sub' => $user->id,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + (2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    ];

    $payload = app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($customClaims);
    return JWTAuth::encode($payload, \Config::get('app.token_secret'));
}

public function signup(Request $request){
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->input('displayName');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    /*$user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));*/
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();
    return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user)]);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `dd` the result ? its probably json object and you need to convert it to string in your js code

Comment: but shldn't console.log function...it is giving not defined..

Comment: try hitting your api with a rest client like postman and see what is returned

Comment: tried it, returns blank...don't see any result

Comment: and the status code is 200 OK?

Comment: yes its -  Status 200 OK

Comment: try using `dd` as suggested by @Gal instead of return statement. See what do you get. Use `dd($this->createToken($user))`

Comment: It took a long time...and gave a 500 Internal Server Error...nothing in laravel.log file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97285/discussion-between-vishal-sh-and-stacy-j).